# Outline text in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, text

Everyone knows that before sending a buyer a file you should to convert text into the outlines for printing.

Photoshop has a button convert to shape - it's a similar as convert to outlines. But the problem is that I can't convert my text into outlines because I merged the text with a new transparent layer, so I can't convert text to outlines. What to do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If I unterstood it correctly you Rasterized your text layer, right?

If yes, then you have to select your text by pressing the box in front of your text layer <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>LM</kbd>(Left mouse click) this will select the outline of your text

---

**1. Select Marquee Tool**

[image: Select Marquee Tool]

---

**2. Right click on your text selection. Select Make Work Path**

[image]

---

**3. Then select the Pen tool on your tools panel. After that select "Shape", its on your toolbar**

[image]

---

**3.5 voilà**
[image]

---

Here's a fast gif https://gfycat.com/EdiblePleasedEidolonhelvum

Comment: While this is all accurate and correct, there's no point to this based on the question.

Comment: Why so? He/She  asked a question how to convert a rasterized text layer to a shape 

'I can't convert my text into outlines because I merged the text with a new transparent layer, so I can't convert text to outlines. What to do?'

Comment: "Everyone knows that before sending a buyer a file you should to convert text into the outlines " --- you don't outline raster type for this.

Comment: If they want to scale the text then yes they need to be converted to shape

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of "creating outlines" (or "convert to shape" in Photoshop) is so that no *live* type is included in the file. That way the person receiving the file does *not* need the font. They also will not be able to edit the type in a live type fashion.

If you have merged your text layer with another layer, and therefore rasterized the text, there is no benefit or need to create outlines of the type. You have *already* removed the "live" type aspect from the text layer. It is then simply pixels like everything else.

Comment: Absolutely correct - and the OP should know that this text is now not scalable without loss of fidelity on the edges. Converting to outlines is best (I know you said this wasn't possible) as it would then be infinitely scalable.